# Stibo STEP: What is the javascript to initiate a node/item in the workflow

Tags: javascript, pim

Stibo STEP: What is the javascript to initiate a node/item in workflow. Don't want to use default wizard screen as I want to just initiate children of the node and not the node itself.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initiate a node into a workflow thus (and it's always wise to check if it's already in there first):

```
var wfID = "ID.of.workflow";

if (!node.isInWorkflow(wfID)) {
    node.startWorkflowByID(wfID, "Put workflow comment here");
}
```

Comment: @PIM Glad it worked. Feel free to mark this as the answer (and maybe upvote :)